# How to make sure a large polyline doesn't go off-road?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline, directions

I have an iOS app that uploads coordinates to a server. These coordinates can then be viewed in a map, through Google Maps. This is shown as a simple polyline. However, due to the GPS not being very precise, the polyline is often off-road.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried using Google's direction service, but it has a limit on how many requests you can send (and there can be a few thousand points on the polyline).

I have no idea how I can solve this problem. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the only way do do this is with manual intervention.  The only way I can think of doing it programmatically would involve lots of queries to the directions service (to get "snap to road" functionality), and that probably would still need someone to check that it got it right (or at least need to include some code to look for extra loops to turn around or detours on to side roads that don't make sense).

Whereas if someone gets directions from start to end then drags them to match the track it would be pretty simple to get a version of the track that follows the roads.

The paper discussed in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/97b05af2412881fd#) might give you some ideas